# Trying to serialize System.Numerics.Quaternion using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net-core, protobuf-net, .net-standard

#### Background Info

I have a .Net Standard 2.0 class library that uses Protobuf-net.grpc's code first approach to define a gRPC service. In this definition I have classes defining different data structures that we are using to record sensor data and serialize this out using protobuf-net. My programs are ingesting serveral hundred thousand large objects /s (which will soon scale into the millions) and are intended to be used in embedded environments.

#### Problem

In my class below, I would like to include as a member a System.Numerics.Quaterion. I cannot seem to get this serialized out. Using static constructors, the RuntimeTypeModel throws exceptions as the Quaternion model has somehow already been created by the time the static constructor is executed. As this is a class library, and I desperately want to avoid invoking the RuntimeTypeModel in each different program using the gRPC service. I'm hoping to find a way to serialize the System.Numerics.Quaternion.

I have tried placing this static constructor runtime definition at the highest level of the class hierarchy to no avail. Exceptions still thrown.

```
[ProtoContract]
    public class IMUData : SensorData, ISensorData
    {
        static IMUData()
        {
            RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Quaternion), false)
                .Add("W")
                .Add("X")
                .Add("Y")
                .Add("Z");
        }

        ... //Other members

        [ProtoMember(8)]
        public Quaternion Orientation
        {
            get; set;
        }

        ... //Other methods and members
    }
```

#### Question

Is what I would like to do even possible, or should I simply create my own Quaternion class and define implicit operators? (I'd rather avoid this as processing billions of these objects takes long enough)

Comment: as a minor aside: IMO, the correct ordering here is `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `W` - as defined by the `Quaternion(float x, float y, float z, float w)` constructor - so if this was me, I'd order them X=1,Y=2,Z=3,W=4; I say this because this type is actually tantalizingly *close* to an inbuilt "tuple-like type" pattern that the library would have recognized and used automatically - where if a type (without suitable annotations) has a constructor that matches all of the members (except for casing on the parameter name), it will infer that it means "the constructor parameter order defines the field numbers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ultimately a timing problem - when the serializer attempts to reflect on `SensorData` to prepare the serializer, the static constructor in `IMUData` *has not yet executed*, so it prepares the serializer with incomplete information, and then *later* the static constructor tries to reconfigure the model - too late.

If you use C# 9.0, you can fix this by using a module initializer instead of a static constructor (if we assume that `SensorData` and `IMUData` are in the same module, which is *probably* a safe assumption). The following works fine, for example:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class IMUData : SensorData //, ISensorData
{
    [ModuleInitializer]
    internal static void Init()
    {
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Quaternion), false)
            .Add("W")
            .Add("X")
            .Add("Y")
            .Add("Z");
    }
```

Note that if you're not using .NET 5 (preview, currently), you can define the necessary attribute yourself:

```cs
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
    internal sealed class ModuleInitializerAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

---

If this isn't an option, you can simply put the model configuration code *much earlier in your application* - ideally during startup, so that it happens *long* before the serializer attempts to start building models.

Comment: Thank you Marc! I'm sorry I didn't come across the module initializer. Thanks for you time and for answering a question that wasn't directly related to protobuf-net!

Comment: @craig they're new in c# 9 which isn't released yet iirc, but you can use it if you have the .net 5 sdk